# How to formalize notion of "up to ordering"

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations, symmetric-groups

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $E$ be a set, and consider the set $E^{[1,n]}$. I want to identify two elements $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ iff they are permutations of each other. What should be the equivalence relation in this case? I thought about
$$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\sim(b_1,\ldots,b_n):=(\exists\sigma)(\sigma\in S_n\ \land\ (\forall i)(1\leq i\leq n\implies a_i=b_{\sigma(i)})).$$
This passes reflexivity and transivity, but I am stuck on proving symmetry. Is this the right equivalence relation?

Comment: shouldn't you use $\sigma^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Yorch I suppose, but I am not sure how that changes things. Can you please explain?

Comment: I meant shouldn't you use the permutation $\sigma^{-1}$ to show it is symmetric ?

Comment: As Yorch says, if $\sigma$ witnesses the fact that $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is related to $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, then $\sigma^{-1}$ witnesses the fact that $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is related to $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.